# Is updating Embedded Documents in MongoDB a Manual process?

Tags: mongodb

I am not overly familiar with Mongodb yet , but I have a question about embedded documents.

I have seen a number of posts which show you how to update embedded documents through some update query.

My question is this: If I have a collection with embedded documents - which is denormalised for performance ; and one of the embedded documents changes, then do I need to manually update all the embedded documents or is there some way of specifying the link in MongoDB to Auto-Update?

For Example:
An Order record might look like the structure below. Note there is a Product item in one of the rows.

Lets say the ItemName field changed to "Product1a" in the product from a different collection and I want to update the product in every single order where this exists. Is that a manual process - or is there a way od setting it up in Mongodb to auto-update embedded documents?

```
{
  "id": "ccc1beb1-e022-11e9-97f0-e7e789106ab2",
  "type": "order",
  "orderNumber": "ORD-100209857x",
  "orderDate": "2019-09-26T17:42:31.000+12:00",
  "orderItems": [
    {
      "discount": 0,
      "price": 24.4944,
      "product": {
        "id": "ccc1beb1-e022-11e9-97f0-e7e789106ab2",
        "itemNumber": "prd1",
        "itemName": "Product1"
      },
      "qty": 4,
      "rowTotal": 97.96,
      "taxAmount": 9.8
    },
    {
      "discount": 0,
      "price": 3.21,
      "itemName": "Shipping",
      "qty": 1,
      "rowTotal": 3.21,
      "taxAmount": 0      
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It is a manual process - but depends. If the `itemName` changes, you may choose to update the Product collection only, or Product collection + active orders only, or Product collection + orders in the last 3 months only, etc. It depends upon your data and application requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by manual process, but here is some sample code to update all the documents

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, {$set:{"orderItems.product.itemName": "updatedProductName"}})
```

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.